# How can I link my C# scripts so that item count influences score in my Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make it so that collecting an item will cause the score to increase. After perusing the documentation for Unity, I have written the following C# scripts. CollectableItem.cs is attached to the items in the game. ScoreBoard.cs is attached to the UI display. I'm getting the error message, "'ScoreBoard.score' is inaccessible due to its protection level." If I make the variables in ScoreBoard.cs public, I get a different error message: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ScoreBoard.score'."

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollectibleItem : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private string itemName;
    [SerializeField] private int pointsValue;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Managers.Inventory.AddItem(itemName);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        ScoreBoard.score += pointsValue;
    }
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreBoard : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Text scoreLabel;
    private int score;

    void Start () {
        score = 0;
    }

    void Update () {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Here is Take 2 on CollectibleItem.cs. Now I'm being informed that "board" does not exist in the current context...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollectibleItem : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private string itemName;
    [SerializeField] private int pointsValue;

    void Start() {
        var uiObject = GameObject.Find("Timer");
        ScoreBoard board = uiObject.GetComponent<ScoreBoard>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Managers.Inventory.AddItem(itemName);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        board.score += pointsValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not able to work because you make a so-called *static access* to the ScoreBoard class. That means you try to change the variable of the ScoreBoard class. What you want to do is to change the variable on one of the instances. When the UI Object is created, an instance of the class of your ScoreBoard-Script is created. Like every item has its own instance of CollectibleItem.
You can get the instance in this way:

```
var uiObject = GameObject.Find("Name of UI Object");
ScoreBoard board = uiObject.GetComponent<ScoreBoard>();
```

You can do this in Start() and save the ScoreBoard variable in the script where your other private variables reside and use it later in the trigger, or you can do this directly in your Trigger function and directly set the score:

```
board.score += pointsValue;
```

EDIT: You have to place the declaration of Scoreboard inside the class:

```
ScoreBoard board;

void Start ()
...
```

Or put the code from start to OnTriggerEnter.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Did you mean for me to edit CollectibleItem.cs? Now I'm getting another error that the name "board" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify

Comment: You can also use a [singleton pattern](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton), which may work well for some situations.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I am still lost, perhaps because I don't fully understand the scripts I used from Unity In Action or the interface between them. I might go back and try to build a simpler game from scratch that implements a scoring system. I would give you an upvote, but I don't have that privilege yet.

Comment: You can accept it as answer with the tick. Maybe try to learn pure C# without Unity